# warning: passing argument 2 of 'calcFx' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, structure, codeblocks

Okay I found the true culprit of my problems, the numbers were scanning in fine for those of you that were here before this edit.

```
void computeDataPoints(F_SELECT *fsPtr, int n,  double points[][n])
{
  int ix;  // for indexing points, i.e. columns of 2D array
  double x; // for incrementing the value of x
  double inc;  // incrementation value of x
  inc = (fsPtr->xf - fsPtr->x0)/(n-1);
  x= fsPtr->x0;

 // Setup loop that computes the points and stores in 2D array
  for (ix=0; ix<NUM_POINTS; ix = ix + 1)
   {
      points[X_IX][ix]=x;
      points[FX_IX][ix]=calcFx(x, &fsPtr->fNumber);
      x = x+ inc;
   }
}
```

I have no Idea how to fix this and have done some searching, if anyone knows how to make this pass properly I'd love you forever

Comment: Can you also show how you are checking if the values are stored correctly?

Comment: you haven't declared `selectFunction(&fselect);` before using it. And [`main` returns `int`, not `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)

Comment: What do you mean by "enter point"? Do you mean you step over the function call to `selectFunction`? Then the debugger might actually be *outside* the `main` function so `fselect` is no longer in scope.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your `do-while` loop exit test doesn't match your error condition.  Specifically, if a number > 5 is entered, the error message will be printed, but the loop will still be exited.

Comment: It's a bit odd to use a double to store an integer.  It works, but it would make a lot more sense to make `fNumber` an `int`.  What will you do if someone enters 2.3?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I left the declarations out, I added that in. It was declared just before the main.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude by point I mean fnumber and a value for x0 and xf

Comment: @TomKarzes noted thanks

Comment: @sla2yer: So... Why are you trying to pass a pointer `&fsPtr->fNumber` to `calcFx` when it clearly expects an integer?

Comment: @AnT using a pointer for the int fNumber that is a variable in a globally declared structure F_SELECT

Comment: @sla2yer: Great. But `calcFx` does not want a pointer. It wants an integer. Why are you trying to pass a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND IT

```
points[FX_IX][ix]=calcFx(x, &fsPtr->fNumber);
```

needs to be

```
points[FX_IX][ix]=calcFx(x, fsPtr->fNumber);
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me when I was looking in the wrong spot

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here since there is really to little go on, but I think the situation is this:

You step through your code in your debugger. You stop at the call to `scanf`, when the debugger cursor is on the `scanf` line. That means the call *hasn't happened yet*. You need to step *one more time* for the `scanf` call to happen.

Another possibility is that you step past the `scanf` call, and the debugger cursor is now on the function closing `}`. Depending on the compiler and its generated code, that might mean that the variable `sfPtr` has gone out of scope and can not be examined reliably by the debugger.

The solution to both the above situation is to add another statement between the `scanf` call and the end of the function. For example a simple `printf` call to print the values:

```
    ...

    // Select a range of x for plotting
    printf("Select range of x for plotting (x0 and xf):");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &sfPtr->x0, &sfPtr->xf);

    // Print the values just entered
    printf("x0 = %f, xf = %f\n", sfPtr->x0, sfPtr->xf);

    // The function ends here
}
```

Besides printing the values, it also gives you an extra step in the debugger to check the values after the call to `scanf`.

Comment: I was using the debugger watches, apparently improperly. However found this bug (as seen in the new edit). Thanks for the advice of using the extra printf